# why did win32service stop working?

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I recently updated my php version to 5.6.22 from 5.5.12. The update went ok and 5.6.22 is working now. After that, the `php_win32service.dll` stopped working. I get the error message :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function win32_query_Service_status()

I tried :

- use the 5.5.12 version
- several DLL's from the web, 32bit, 64bit TS and NTS
- restore only the DLL file from backup
- restore the entire WAMP PHP folder from backup

Nothing I seem to use, works. All DLL's give me that error message.

Comment: This question is actually better asked on the superuser forum.  SO is mainly code-based Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did that solved the problem :

1. I completely uninstalled WAMP, removed every trace in the system.
2. Re-installed WAMP with same settings (**don't start it yet**).
3. Delete WAMP folder
4. Restore WAMP folder from backup
5. Start WAMP

`php_win32service.dll` worked again like before. I believe win23service is just not compatible with 5.6.22